# Asking for the username just once then saving it to localStorage

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to build a page where a prompt shows to ask the user to type a username, then save it to local Storage. My problem is that the prompt keeps showing up everytime i reload the page, how can i show the prompt just once to save the username then not display it once there is a valid username saved in local Storage ? I'm using vanilla javascript with its modern features.

Edit: This code solves the problem, thanks to @Prime for the precious help !

```
let username;
const data = localStorage.getItem('username');
if (!data){
    username = prompt('Please type your username', 'you');
    localStorage.setItem('username', username);
}
```

Comment: post your code what you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if username already exists in localStorage in advance.

```
const data = localStorage.getItem('username');
if (!data) {
// prompt
}
```